# (basic but confusing) Noodles - is or are?

Tags: grammatical-number

It is obvious that "are" is used in cases like "These noodles are tasty", but what about the following?

I.
variant 1. These are pasta noodles.
variant 2. This is pasta noodles.

II.
variant 1. What are ramen noodles?
variant 2. What is ramen noodles?

Comment: Stick with the plural.

Comment: I agree that 'noodles' is definitely plural. However, 'spaghetti' is plural in Italian, but it has become conventional for English speakers to treat the word as uncountable, as though 'it' were a substance.

Comment: @KateBunting You might want to add an answer before the question is closed.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>*This is a duplicate, but its counterpart is not easy to find. At least searching for "ramen noodles" will make **this** answer easy to find for the future.*</sub>

If you're treating *pasta noodles* as **a single thing** (say a particular packet), then it's singular.

> This packet contains rice, and this one is pasta noodles.

However if you're looking at each noodle individually, then it's plural.

> What I have in this hand are grains of rice; but in this one are pasta noodles.

The same applies to case II, although I can't think of even a potentially-idiomatic example for "What is ramen noodles?" It's the sort of sentence that someone learning English might use when they encounter a phrase they've not heard before.

> — I like ramen noodles.
>
> — What is "ramen noodles"?

(Note the quotes around the phrase.) That question would always be "What are ramen noodles?" in idiomatic English.

Comment: Thank you all for your replies. Well, truth to be told, personally I can hardly be described as a novice English learner / speaker, but for some reason "What are ramen noodles?" (in a sense of a question a person completely unfamiliar with with the thing might have) just doesn't sound right...

Comment: Some words don't have separate plurals, of course. The sentences "Where is the sheep?" and "Where are the sheep." are both correct under different circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that 'noodles' is definitely plural.

However, 'spaghetti' is plural in Italian, but it has become conventional for English speakers to treat the word as uncountable, as though 'it' were a substance – presumably because people didn't realise that it was the plural form.